# Convert Linq to Sql Expression to Expression Tree which uses join to function table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Can anybody give me ideas how the create an expression tree for following Linq query:

```
dataContext.Companies.Where(c=> !dataContext.TableFunction(1).Any(tf=> tf.ID = c.ID))
```

So basically it's similar to following SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Company] c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                  FROM [dbo].TableFunction(1) tf 
                  WHERE c.ID = tf.ID)
```

Any ideas would be good to have. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Using LINQPad, you can assign it in a lambda to a variable (e.g. `Expression<Action<IQueryable<Company>>>`) and then dump the variable.